# Where can I find information about the legend of Ulug' Bek and dancers?

Tags: myth-identification

There is a legend that Ulug' Bek, the grandchild of Amir Timur (aka Tamerlane), invited dancers and asked them to dip their feet into a blue coloring and dance on a huge roll of paper. Later he laid the resulting picture over the map of the sky.

I am looking for any information related to that legend.